# Word VBA: how to obtain an exact search result with find.execute when text is formatted as hidden

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using  `Selection.Find.Execute` or `MyRange.Find.Execute` within a text containing revision marks while having set `Options.DeletedTextMark = wdDeletedTextMarkHidden`. Alternatively I'm searching within a text in which certain strings are formatted with `Font.Hidden = True`.

If immediately before or after the search result there will be hidden text, it will be included with the search result and any subsequent operation (like `Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdGreen`) will include the hidden portion.

Is there an easy way of making sure that the search result corresponds exactly to the searched term?

Answer (score 0):

The best work-around I have found so far is the following function:

```
Function ExactRange(Optional rngFoundRange) as Boolean

  If IsMissing(rngFoundRange) Then Set rngFoundRange = Selection.Range
  Vi_LenInitial = rngFoundRange.End - rngFoundRange.Start

  rngFoundRange.SetRange _
    Start:=rngFoundRange.Characters(1).End - 1, _ 
    End:=rngFoundRange.Characters(Len(rngFoundRange)).End

  Vi_LenExact = rngFoundRange.End - rngFoundRange.Start
  ExactRange = IIf(Vi_LenInitial = Vi_LenExact, True, False)
End Function
```

The function will be `True` if the found range was exact, it will be `False` if it was not exact and needed to be adjusted. In any case, after execution the found range should exactly match the search string.